# How to change the datatype to double to Int32 in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to convert the double to Int32 in Mongodb .I am able to convert the value to Int32 but not in desired format .My Document looks line below .When I try to change the Value 1.0 to 1 , the value is getting changed to 0 in Int32 but I need to change to 1 Int32.Similarly I have multiple documents and format need to be change to 2.0 to 2 ,3.0 to 3.I am not sure what is wrong with my query Any help would be appreciated .

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62fb48824c03a80001c2b5a7"),
    "Type" : {   
        "Value" : 1.0,        
    },   
}

db.TestCollection.find(
    {
        'Type.Value':{$exists:true}
    },
    {
        'value':"$Value"
    }
   
).forEach(function(doc){
   var data=value;
    db.TestCollection.update(
    { _id:doc._id },
      
        {
            $set:{
                'Type.Value':NumberInt(data)
            }
            
            
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Line `var data=value;` does not make any sense. Should be rather `var data = doc.value;`

And `{ 'value': "$Value" }` does not make sense either. `"$Value"` is null. Should be rather `{ 'value': "$Type.Value" }`

Anyway, you don't need a loop, you can update the values with a single command:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { 'Type.Value': { $exists: true } },
   [
      { $set: { 'Type.Value': { $toInt: "$Type.Value" } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Domschett  , Appreciate your help .I am able to update the values as Int32 .I need avoid the updating of empty value for Type.Value == Empty Bocz it is updating as a NAN .Please suggest

Comment: @Rose Then use filter `{ 'Type.Value': { $type: 'decimal' } }`

Comment: I tried to use { 'Type.Value': { $type: 'decimal' } } but is throwing an error MongoServerError: Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: No digits

Comment: Are you sure? No typo?